# $F(x,y)=(x^2,y)$ is not differentiable (According to WA), what am I missing?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, wolfram-alpha

Either wolfram alpha is getting crazy or I just completely misunderstood differentiability.

Shouldn't it be enough for the partial derivatives to exist and to be continuous? Would the differential not just be the jacobian? So, it should be differentiable...but is not?

PS: This is part of a wider question that goes
$f(z)= x^2+iy$. Am I correct with the corresponding $F$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: What does wolframalpha tell you? Can it check for differentiability? You are right, when the partial derivatives exist and they are continuous then, then the function is (total) differentiable.

Comment: It says it's not differentiable, and i'm completely blindsided by it

Comment: Are you asking about differentiability as a function $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ or as a function $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$? Because they are VERY different in nature...

Comment: @Teddy38 In this particular case, $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ . If I understand correctly, once i prove that this function is differentiable I can use cauchy-riemann to give it a go for $\mathbb{C}$-differentiability, no?

Comment: I for one have no idea what W|A is trying to say. Here is one W|A link for [$(x^2,y)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+x%5E2+%2B+iy+differentiable) and another for [$x^2+iy$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+x%5E2+%2B+iy+differentiable). The "assumptions" are a little different in both cases, maybe that hints as to what it might be thinking. [W|A even says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+%28x%2Cy%29+differentiable) that $(x,y)$ is not differentiable...so I don't think its about the $\Bbb C$ differentiability

Comment: What input did you give to W|A exactly? It is not very intelligent so it could have misunderstood what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiability in $\mathbb{C}$ is not the same as in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Differentiable complex functions must satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, which is not the case of $f(z)=x^2+i y$.

Comment: Indeed, i added the second part just to be sure i was on the right path. The idea was to show that F defined as a real function is differentiable and then the cauchy-Riemann equations

Comment: @PabloChávezRomero Ok, but $F$ is surely differentiable (because $F_1=x^2$ and $F_2=y$ have continuous partial derivatives) an so the key point will be the CR conditions.